# LG V10 Phone stuck in BootLoop - recovery data

Tags: recovery-mode, boot-loop, data-recovery

I have a LG V10 Phone.  It is stuck in the BootLoop mode.  I want to recover the data from the phone.  Is there a way to recover the data without getting into the system?  Please advice.  Thanks, John

Comment: Please explain in the question the cause of bootloop - what you exactly did in your device that caused it..

Answer (score 0):

The bootloop bug is a known issue with LG V10. If you have insurance on the phone, even if it is out of the original manufacturer warranty, you can go to your local cellular provider and have them cross-ship a refurb replacement to you.
**To get to your data before getting your phone fixed or replaced, here's a link to a very sound incremental methodology:** https://appuals.com/fix-lg-v10-bootloop/

The best thing about this process is that you start with the simplest solution and progress, and you'll learn more about the Android OS capabilities along the way no matter what your final outcome is.